# Unexpected token x in JSON at position 0

Tags: angular

I am getting the error: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 0

I'm not sure what is causing this issue.  Researching the issue I found out that the majority of the time it's bad payload.  However I don't see anything wrong with my payload.

How can I further debug this and.or resolve the issue? It does make a successful call and adds the item. (Just my interceptor is reporting an error back)

Payload:

```
{"name":"xx","description":"aaabbb"}
```

My Call:

```
// This is in my component.  Just illustrating here what it is set to.
jsonHeaderOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };


  public addCall(dataObject: any) {
    let body = JSON.stringify(dataObject);

    return this.httpClient
      .post(this.uri, body, this.jsonHeaderOptions);
  };
```

Comment: Why are you sending body as string (JSON.stringify) while setting the content type as json?

Comment: Where do you get this error?

Comment: I get the error in my HttpInterceptor that I created. It comes back with 200 OK, with this error.

Comment: You don't need to set the `Content-Type` header. Angular will do this for you automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable HttpClient's default json parsing, by passing responseType like below.

```
return this.httpClient
  .post(this.uri, body, { responseType: 'text'});
```

Comment: I did that I went from 200 to Error: Status: 415 Text: Unsupported Media Type

Comment: try removing JSON.stringify(dataObject); you don't have to do it.